# readonly parameter for a function in typescript

Tags: typescript

How to mark each 'id' property of elements in the returned array as readonly in following function 'excludeYoungPersons' and does not modify the original array?

```
type Person = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
function excludeYoungPersons(person: readonly Person[]): readonly Person[] {
  let data = [...person];
  const result = data.filter(item => item.age > 30)
  return result;
}
export { excludeYoungPersons };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the output type as follows (note the function signature):

```
type Person = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
function excludeYoungPersons(person: readonly Person[]): ReadonlyArray<Readonly<Person>> {
  let data = [...person];
  const result = data.filter(item => item.age > 30)
  return result;
}

const input: Person[] = [{
  id: "xyz",
  name: "Mary",
  age: 32
}]

const result = excludeYoungPersons(input);
result[0] = { id: "nmp", name: "John", age: 41 };   //error
result[0].id = "rst";  //error!
```

That is, by using `ReadonlyArray` you'll return an interface which limits the array to anything non-destructive. Then, with `Readonly<Person>`, you'll consider the actual type as it were:

```
type Person = {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly name: string;
  readonly age: number;
};
```

Bear in mind that it's a compile type checking. If you need something stronger, you'd better turn to a class instead of a POJO (Plain-Old Javascript Object).

EDIT: if you need just a field to be read-only, you can write as follows:

```
type TResultPerson =
  Omit<Person, "id"> & {
    readonly id: string;
  }

function excludeYoungPersons(person: readonly Person[]): ReadonlyArray<TResultPerson> {
  // (same as original)
}
```

Here is the behavior:

```
const result = excludeYoungPersons(input);
result[0] = { id: "nmp", name: "John", age: 41 };   //error
result[0].id = "rst";  //error!
result[0].name = "George";  //OK
```

EDIT: As @Darryl Noakes pointed out in the comments below, there's another solution which can become useful if you need to solve in many places.

You can define somewhere in your code this helper:

```
type SemiReadonly<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Readonly<Pick<T, K>>;
```

This basically does exactly what you ask, but in more flexible way. So, in order to make read-only only the "id" field:

```
function excludeYoungPersons(person: readonly Person[]): SemiReadonlyArray<Person, "id"> {
  // (same as original)
}
```

If you wish to make read-only the "name" field as well:

```
function excludeYoungPersons(person: readonly Person[]): SemiReadonlyArray<Person, "id" | "name"> {
  // (same as original)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mario Vernari for your answer, but i am not going to consider actual type to be readonly. I want to make only `id` to be readonly in 'cost result' of function

Comment: @Sahar I added what you ask

Comment: Also, you don't need the temp var, as `.filter()` doesn't mutate the source array.

Comment: Instead of doing `Omit<Person, "id"> & { readonly id: string }`, you could do `Omit<Person, "id"> & Readonly<Pick<Person, "id">>`.

Comment: You can easily extend that form, such as doing multiple properties. You could even extract it to a `SemiReadonly<T, K>` generic (`type SemiReadonly<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Readonly<Pick<T, K>>`).

Comment: @DarrylNoakes you're right, but I wanted to keep as simplest as possible the form. However, I'll add your proposal for completeness of the answer.

Comment: @MarioVernari To clarify my suggestion, I saw just the general pattern of `Omit` + `Pick` as useful because it means **you don't need to write out the type of the field again,** just the key. The rest is more side effects of it being just composable generics.